# How to make conjugate transpose of this matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

The 4x1 matrix is defined as:

```
q1 = {{-((
 I (-I p0 p1 + p1^2 - p0 p2 + p2^2 + e (p0 - I p1 - p2 - p3) + 
    m (p0 - I p1 - p2 - p3) - p0 p3 + p3^2))/(
 2 m^(3/2) Sqrt[(e + m)/m]))}, {(
I p0 p1 + p1^2 - p0 p2 + p2^2 + p0 p3 + p3^2 + 
 e (p0 + I p1 - p2 + p3) + m (p0 + I p1 - p2 + p3))/(
2 m^(3/2) Sqrt[(e + m)/m])}, {(
I p0 p1 + p1^2 + p0 p2 + p2^2 + p0 p3 + p3^2 + 
 e (p0 + I p1 + p2 + p3) + m (p0 + I p1 + p2 + p3))/(
2 m^(3/2) Sqrt[(e + m)/m])}, {(
I (-I p0 p1 + p1^2 + p0 p2 + p2^2 + e (p0 - I p1 + p2 - p3) + 
   m (p0 - I p1 + p2 - p3) - p0 p3 + p3^2))/(
2 m^(3/2) Sqrt[(e + m)/m])}};
```

Now to get conjugate transpose:

```
r1 = MatrixForm[Assuming[{p0, p1, p2, p3, e, m} \[Element] Reals, Simplify@ConjugateTranspose[q1]]]
```

But the above code doesn't seem to evaluate the expression fully. What to do?

Comment: Try `Assuming[{p0, p1, p2, p3, e, m} \[Element] Reals && e > 0 && m > 0, FullSimplify @ ConjugateTranspose[q1]]`

Comment: I also recommend you take heed of tip number 8 in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/43522).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks man but, still some issue persists, 2 of the elements in the matrix output comes as: {-((I (p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2 + 
     Conjugate[
      p0 (I p1 + p2 - p3) + e (p0 + I p1 + p2 - p3) + 
       m (p0 + I p1 + p2 - p3)]))/(2 m Sqrt[e + m]))

Comment: How about `ComplexExpand@ConjugateTranspose[q1]`?

Comment: @user64494 Yeah it does evaluate the expression and makes it more complicated by outputting cos and sin. I have to further multiply the matrix and simplify it. Does both the matrices need to be in ComplexExpand form?. The end result is still not coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of all `Conjugate` heads, you sometimes need to give Mathematica an extra push because there is no measure of "simplicity" that always does what people want. Here's an example:

```
Assuming[{p0, p1, p2, p3, e, m} \[Element] Reals && e > 0 && m > 0,
 FullSimplify[
  ConjugateTranspose[q1],
  ComplexityFunction -> Function[LeafCount[#] + 100*Count[#, _Conjugate, {0, Infinity}]]
  ]
]
```

> [image]

The `ComplexityFunction` is effectively a way of telling Mathematica that you'll get very cross every time you see `Conjugate` appear in the output.

Comment: One sees `Conjugate[(0. - 1. I) p0 p1 - 1. p0 p2 + 
  0.002 (p0 - (0. + 1. I) p1 - 1. p2 - 1. p3)` and similar terms in the output.

Comment: @user64494 Huh? That's not what I'm getting at all. See screenshot included in the edit. Are you sure you cleared all variables before trying this?

Comment: Sjoerd Smit: You are right: after cleaning your code and mine perform the same.

Comment: I got the conjugate. Although I don't really understand how the complexity function command works. I have to further multiply 1x4 matrix with 4x1 matrix and get a scalar. But the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@ConjugateTranspose[q1], Assumptions -> {p0, p1, p2, p3, e, m} \[Element] Reals && e > 0 &&  m > 0]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{i \left(-\text{p3} (e+m+\text{p0})+e \text{p0}+i e \text{p1}-e \text{p2}+m \text{p0}+i m \text{p1}-m \text{p2}+i \text{p0} \text{p1}-\text{p0} \text{p2}+\text{p1}^2+\text{p2}^2+\text{p3}^2\right)}{2 m \sqrt{e+m}} & \frac{e (\text{p0}-i \text{p1}-\text{p2}+\text{p3})+m (\text{p0}-i \text{p1}-\text{p2}+\text{p3})-i \text{p0} \text{p1}-\text{p0} \text{p2}+\text{p0} \text{p3}+\text{p1}^2+\text{p2}^2+\text{p3}^2}{2 m \sqrt{e+m}} & \frac{e (\text{p0}-i \text{p1}+\text{p2}+\text{p3})+m (\text{p0}-i \text{p1}+\text{p2}+\text{p3})-i \text{p0} \text{p1}+\text{p0} \text{p2}+\text{p0} \text{p3}+\text{p1}^2+\text{p2}^2+\text{p3}^2}{2 m \sqrt{e+m}} & -\frac{i \left(-\text{p3} (e+m+\text{p0})+e \text{p0}+i e \text{p1}+e \text{p2}+m \text{p0}+i m \text{p1}+m \text{p2}+i \text{p0} \text{p1}+\text{p0} \text{p2}+\text{p1}^2+\text{p2}^2+\text{p3}^2\right)}{2 m \sqrt{e+m}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Transpose[q1] // Expand /. I -> -I

LeafCount[FullSimplify[%,{e>0,m>0}]]
(*258*)
```

Comment: `LeafCount[%]` performs `1570` in comparison to `258` produced by other answers..

Comment: Simplification gives the same leafcount !